# Data transfer modifier / UVs generation

Tags: uv, modifiers

I am trying to transfer UVs from one model to another model, but it does not work (the destination UV map does not change). What could be the reasons for this?

**More information:** Seams are the same (same vertex positions), but the other vertices are different.

Comment: It is very difficult to debug your problem without screenshots/a .blend file. You can upload the .blend file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). You can edit your answer to include screenshots. Also, please include more information about what your problem is, what you are doing, and what exactly is not working.

Comment: Thanks. At last, I tried it another way, using DataTransfer/Data in the tool panel, and here it works well. But it does not work using the DataTransfer modifier (options are the same, but the result is not)